# Is it possible to call include/require from a class object for the current file?

Tags: class, object, include

So here's my idea. I have a class that takes a file, checks for a specific snippet, str_replaces it, and returns it back. Kind of like how a simplified smarty works with tag replacement

so for example if my index.php looks like:

```
<?php
include('file.php');
....
?>
```

it becomes:

```
<?php
include($myClass->edit('file.php');
....
?>
```

That works fine. But instead of that, would it be possible to have the actual include() function replaced by my own?

making it:

```
<?php
$myClass->myinclude('file.php');
....
?>
```

The myinclude() function in my class would be:

```
public function myinclude ($file) { 
    include($this->edit('file.php'));
}
```

But it doesn't work, I assume because I can't call the include from within the class and expect it to return back to the calling index.php file.

Is there some trick around this?

Answer (score 0):

**include** is not a function but a language construct. When your php is executed the contents of included file (or even php executable strings) are copied at the point of inclusion.

Comment: Is there no way to maybe use ob_start() to get the data buffered, then return that back to the index page?